# What is SAS when it pertains to databases?

Tags: sql-server, sas

I'm reading a description for some requirements and it says SAS, and it seems to be related to sql server and potentially access?

I've tried searching on it and I'm not really sure what to make of it.

Can someone shed some light as to what this technology might be.

My guess is that is is some sort of scripting language that is used for database transfering?

Is there a website that describes SAS in detail?  is it a acronym or what?

thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAS is quite large and has many different packages.  One of these is called [SAS/Access](http://www.sas.com/software/data-management/access/index.html), which provides tools for reading/writing to many, many different data sources.  The data appears native to SAS so you can write your code in the usual SAS way.  The SQL pass-through facility translates the SAS functions and code into the native language of the database.

Answer (score 2):

SAS is a database platform (usual reference).  Their documentation is here:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/index.html

They also supply many other tools, but most people just refer to the interpreted SAS scripting and data mining tools.  As fair warning, if you don't have experience with it, don't accept requirements using it unless there is time for training.  Familiarity with SQL Databases does not translate well to SAS because the data organization and language are very different.  They also produce a compiled language for building windows type forms.  This is an entirely different language to learn if required.  Make sure you understand those requirements fully.

Answer (score 1):

SAS is a data analysis package. It relates to SQL Server and Access in that a relational database can be used as a data source in SAS.

Comment: SAS is not part of SQL Server per se. The wikipedia article is fairly detailed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29. More specific information depends on exactly what you're after -- ETL, OLAP, data analysis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context that might be [Serial attached SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI) (a hardware technology) or [SAS software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29) (a software system for statistisal analysis).
Wikipedia is (as usual) a good starting place to read about both.

Or probably SAS means something else, that just happens to match the same TLA :-) .
It might help if you provide more details about the context.